# How to fix "Is Positive or Negative" C script?

Tags: c

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void    func_putchar(char c)
{
    write(1, &c, 1);
}

void    func_putchar(char c);

void    func_is_negative(char *n){
    if (n >= 0)
    {
        func_putchar('P');
    }
    else
    {
        func_putchar('N');
    }
}

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ){
    char n = atoi (argv[1]);
    func_is_negative(&n);
}
```

---

I tried inserting a number through terminal, however each time I get a random result, it's either positive or negative.
I think the code doesn't check the number submitted or translates it badly with atoi()

Comment: [`atoi` returns an int](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/).

Comment: Are your numbers between -128 and 127? Otherwise you'll get overflow, as you're using char, which is just 1 byte

Comment: Copying answers to the comments section; that's a new one

Comment: Since zero is neither negative nor positive, it might be interesting to discuss [nonnegative integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_number#:~:text=Signed%20numbers,-Main%20article%3A%20Sign&text=Because%20zero%20is%20neither%20positive,Zero%20is%20a%20neutral%20number.) with your instructor and how that designation is useful.

Comment: C is _not_ a scripting language... Software development is a field where precision matters. Getting your terms mixed up only results in confusion, which is never good.

Comment: `atoi()` has zero error reporting and will silently fail returning `0` for any non-numeric string, e.g. `atoi ("my cow");` If you are using `argv[1]` for your number, at least do `int n; if (sscanf (argv[1], "%d", &n) != 1)) { fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n"); return 1; }` so you provide minimal validation of the conversion. `strtol()` would provide even more fine-grained error reporting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do stange things in my point of view,
Why `char n = atoi(argv[1])`, better use `int n = atoi(argv[1])` because atoi return a int or a long.

After, I don't think that you need a pointer of n , `func_is_negative(n);` looks better for your case.

so replace the prototype of your functions too, `void    func_is_negative(int n)` looks better cause you are using integers.

If I don't say mess, when you do : `if (n >= 0)`  whith `char *n`, you are comparing a pointer (char *) whith 0 and the value of a pointer can't be 0 or less

Comment: `because atoi return a int or a long` no `atoi` returns only an int

Answer (score 1):

You're checking whether the *pointer to the char* is greater than or equal to `0`. After sign conversion, this may or may not be the case at any given time.

Check `*n`, not `n`. Or don't pass a pointer in in the first place (there's no need to).

You may also wish to consider using `int` rather than `char`, as your input is quite constrained at the moment and prone to overflows.